# Detect camera looking down - FPSController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, camera

Currently I am using :

```
Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
forward.y = 0;
float viewDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward).eulerAngles.y;
```

In order to detect the rotation (left + right) of the camera. However, I can't figure out how to get the angle the camera is facing when looking up and down? It's probably something simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Surely your camera has, orientation of a line going from a,b,c to d,e,f, lets say the terrain shows x is always 0 = eg its flat.  if your co-ords for your camera are xyz orientated, if d>a then camera is looking up, if a>d then camera is looking down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dot product](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html).

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, Vector3.up)) >= 0.95f) {
    Debug.Log("Looking up or Looking down");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was along the lines of what I was looking for.